# mainCRTStartup() does not call main()

Tags: windows, windbg, winsock

I ran a simple winsock client and placed the instruction `_asm int 3` before `WSAStartup`. I placed a breakpoint at `WS2_32!send`, then `g`, then a breakpoint at `ndis!NdisSendNetBufferLists`, and saw the following calltrace (with some parts omitted):

```
00                   ndis!NdisSendNetBufferLists
...
1b 80d8ff20 89617a1f ndis!ndisMiniportDpc+0xe2
1c 80d8ff48 82891f7e ndis!ndisInterruptDpc+0xaf
1d 80d8ffa4 82891de0 nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0xfa
1e 80d8fff4 8289157c nt!KiRetireDpcList+0xd5
1f 8c3704f4 828082af nt!KiDispatchInterrupt+0x2c
20 8c37050c 82808449 hal!HalpCheckForSoftwareInterrupt+0x83
21 8c370518 82894d91 hal!HalEndSystemInterrupt+0x67
22 8c370518 82840e8f nt!KeUpdateSystemTimeAssist+0x5d
23 8c3705c4 82b652bf nt!KeThawExecution+0x1c8
24 8c3705dc 828e64ae nt!KdExitDebugger+0x67
25 8c3705f4 82b65604 nt!KdpReport+0xd5
26 8c370620 828e4b7b nt!KdpTrap+0x102
27 8c370bc4 8286f932 nt!KiDispatchException+0x21e
28 8c370c2c 82870a3f nt!CommonDispatchException+0x4a
29 8c370c2c 766e6c1a nt!KiTrap03+0x263
2a 001efec0 00211bfe WS2_32!send+0x1
2b 001efed4 00211af1 
client!__scrt_narrow_environment_policy::initialize_environment+0x2e 
[f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 78] 
2c 001eff2c 0021199d client!_RTC_Shutdown+0x251 
[f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 283] 
2d 001eff34 00211c68 client!_RTC_Shutdown+0xfd 
[f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 326] 
2e 001eff3c 777cefac client!mainCRTStartup+0x8
[f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp @ 17] 
2f 001eff48 77673628 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
30 001eff88 776735fb ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
31 001effa0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Observe that `client!mainCRTStartup` did not call `client!main`. Why? Shouldn't it call `client!main`?

Additional info: I used kernel debugging on Virtual Windows 7x86. The winsock client and server are in the same virtual machine (configured to use Bridged), but this problem is also present if they are on different machines.

Comment: It did not get that far yet, it is still busy initializing static state.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean? When I placed a breakpoint at `WS2_32!send`, `mainCRTStartup` called `main`, but when I placed another breakpoint `ndis!NdisSendNetBufferLists`, `mainCRTStartup` did not call `main`

Comment: Before main() can be called, the CRT first needs to initialize global variables.  Could be the constructor of a C++ class for example, but a wild guess when I have no idea what the code looks like.  It is actually still busy handling the INT3, maybe the remote debug engine got involved.

Comment: @HansPassant So, the calltrace from `KiTrap03` onwards means that it is handling `KiTrap03`, rather than actually executing client?